# Represented by three stripes

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Replace the question mark. The answer is 7 letters long.

---

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Germany

Solution:

> Reflect each of the three $3 \times 3$ squares on the top of the puzzle to form the following word square:
>  `AUT BEL CZE`
>  `DNK FRA LUX`
>  `NLD POL CHE`
>
>  Each of these is an [ISO alpha-3 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3): respectively, they are Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, France, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Poland, and Switzerland.
>
>  As visually represented by the bottom image, the only country bordering all nine of these countries is $\boxed{\text{Germany}}$.

Comment: Correct and well done!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is:

> Germany - represented by a tricolour of Black, Red and Gold

Because:

> If you rotate the three grids about the circular pivots so that they coincide:
>  [image: Three letter grids with rotation arrows]

> Then mirror to get the letters the right way round, and you end up with the following grid:
>
> ```
>   AUT    BEL    CZE
>
>   DNK    FRA    LUX
>
>   NLD    POL    CHE
> ```

> These are all three-letter country codes for:
>
> ```
>  Austria      Belgium  Czechia
>
>  Denmark      France   Luxembourg
>
>  Netherlands  Poland   Switzerland
> ```

> Those are (in alphabetical order) the nine countries bordering Germany, as clued by the bottom half of the image.

Comment: Answered 2 hours ago, answer score of 2, from a user with 2222 reputation. Sorry, can't upvote.

Comment: At least it isn't last Tuesday :-)

Comment: @Bass Reminds me of how after solving my last puzzle, you climbed into 6th place overall with a total rep of exactly 66,666 :)

Comment: Well done! This is of course correct but I'm giving the tick to Flame since I can see he answered a bit earlier than you.

Comment: @noedne I noticed that too :)